# Where are my static files in a Dokku based installation?

Tags: django, deployment, static-files, dokku

I finished a Dokku deployment on a Digitalocean server. My application seems to work, except for my static files.

Here are the relevant parts of my settings.py file:

```
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).absolute().ancestor(2)

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child('static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child('staticroot')
```

Does someone know how can I point my app at my static files on a Dokku based system?

Though it's not answering my question, we're currently serving the static files from AWS S3, and that works. It makes my question less urgent, but I still would like to know if it is possible to solve it "locally".

Answer (score -2):

You may need to do a few things

1. run `./manage.py collectstatic` to move static files to your static folder
2. Update your web server config so that `/static/` points to the static folder.

Have you done this already?

Comment: i did run ./manage.py collectstatic (although it does it automatically during git push). I'm not sure what do you mean in (2). How should i do that (aside from my settings as written above)? Thanks!

Comment: are you running `apache` or `nginx` or some other webserver?

Comment: nginx, but the whole deployment is through dokku.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Deploying for the first time and having this issue.